# how can I access router system files?

Tags: router, authentication, system-file

I want to access my router's files but I don't know how. I own BaudTec router. I tried `\\192.168.1.1` , it asks for username-password I gave the same as when I login router web interface but I couldn't login. Probably it needs something else, I don't know... Does any know what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: The default IP address for home routers is usually 192.168.2.1.

Comment: @ChrisF the routers I've seen usually have 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1, but never 192.168.2.1.  And the fact that its asking for a username/password leads to believe that it is connecting to something.

Comment: @heavyd - mine's 192.168.2.1. Interesting.

Comment: @Sotiris what IP do you use to connect to the web interface?

Comment: @Sotiris also, what model of router do you have?

Comment: I own a baudTec router (I don't know exactly the model). I connect on web interface through 192.168.1.1

Comment: Are you trying to access files stored on a SMB share connected to your router or do you want to actually get the image (operating system) that your router uses to boot?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to connect to your gateway local IP address, which may be different for any router but most always starts with 192.168.#(1-3).#(1-3) and can be obtained by typing `ipconfig` into your command prompt.

[image]

Under LAN there should be your local IP address and the gateway (router) you are connected to. Typing this in a browser will open your configuration via HTML webpages, your login SHOULD be what username and password you're using to even go on the internet.

Comment: The OP already tried visiting the router's IP.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to flash your device with an alternate firmware.

However, finding a compatibly firmware maybe be difficult with an off brand like BaudTec.

Your only other hope is to exploit a security vulnerability in your router.

Here's one:
https://github.com/abdelsalamshahlol/PLDT-Baudtec-login-credentials-exploit.

Don't know what model you have so this may or may not work.

here's another article:

http:\cgi.di.uoa.gr\~xenakis\Published\Technical_Reports\ZTExploit_Paper.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2942DYAYpaac663n_aucq-